# Possible to fit stock charts onto a tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, diagrams

I am new to Latex, but I would like to compare a 'normal' function I define against the stock price development of a particular security. Of course this data is very erratic making it impossible for me to explicitly define it. So how may I compare the two graphs as tikzpicture elements. Furthermore, I would like to compare both by planting the respective graphs adjacent to one another. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Welcome! This question needs in my opinion much more details and clarity. What do you mean by "compare"? You can just show these graphs side by side. Anyway, consider completely rewriting the whole post and also to show an example of what you have tried.

Comment: You need IMO multiple objects to do that. Check on the site the questions related to normal distribution and brownian motion. There are plenty. It'll give us a clearer view of what you need and a working example to start helping.